# exchanging something with someone else or exchanging with someone else's?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

"...everyone was exchanging theirs with someone else’s"
or
"...everyone was exchanging theirs with someone else"

You could exchange your work with a person, or you could exchange your work with that person's work. How to think about this, and which one is more correct?

exchange with:

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/exchange+with

Comment: I think usually, you'd exchange *something **for*** something else. But others may think ***with*** is okay there.

Comment: I see. So the context here is this is a writers group and everyone brought a piece of their work to exchange with (?) another person, in pairs. @FumbleFingers

Comment: I'd say "exchanging with someone else" or "exchanging for someone else's"/"exchanging for something else".